# Angularjs, $resource: how to get inserted object?

Tags: ajax, angularjs, callback, angularjs-resource

I need to get an inserted object immediately after insertion has been done. But this is a problem with Angularjs $resource.

```
module.factory('SearchQueries', function($resource){         
  return $resource('/instances/searches/:_id', {_id: '@id'});
});

var new_search = new SearchQueries({query: query});

new_search.$save(function(new_query){
  console.log(new_query);
  console.log(new_query.id, new_query.query);                           
  console.log(new_query.$get()); // This is undefined                   
  $scope.searchQueries.push(new_query);
});
```

Server response:

```
{"query": "inserted text", "id": 53}
```

`new_query` printed in a console:

```
h {query: "f7b1b2214bda4aa29b7ef5029c918590", id: 53, $get: function, $save: function,     $query: function…}
$$hashKey: "01J"
id: 53
query: "inserted text"
```

`new_query.id, new_query.query` printed in a console:

```
53 "f7b1b2214bda4aa29b7ef5029c918590"
```

Instead of inserted text I have some kind of hash. By the way, what the hash is this?

In the template a bit of millisecond a `new_query` is a hash, after `$get` is done (success) the `new_query` is inserted text. **How to get inserted text directly after `$get` successed?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new_query` is a `SearchQueries` instance with the data response from the server. It seems like your server responds with `{query: "f7b1b2214bda4aa29b7ef5029c918590", id: 53}`, this is not created by Angular. The $ and $$ properties are from the `SearchQueries` prototype. If you want to print the result from `new_query.$get()` you should do it in a callback function:

```
new_query.$get(function(result){
  console.log(result);
});
```